# Webconfig of an asp.net mvc3 website (deployment)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, web-config

Today I deployed my first asp.net mvc3 website. It seems like the connection to the database does not work. I need to say, that I am a total newbie with the configuration of the web.config file.
I deployed alle files from VS 2010 and can reach sites that are not using the database. I created the database with the Entities.edmx.sql file. All tables were created.

The Web.config in VS 2010:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="EntitiesContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.Entities.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.Entities.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=catalog_name;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Users/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" cacheDuration="5" enableLocalization="true" scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true" includeAssembliesForScan="" excludeAssembliesForScan="" attributesToIgnore="visibility" nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider" controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/PageNotFound/" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I know that i need to turn off the customErrors mode. My host gave me the following connection string to use. I tried to use it for the ApplicationServices and EntitiesContainer but it did not work.

```
workstation id=the_workstation_id;packet size=4096;user id=username;pwd=password;data source=data_source_name;persist security info=False;initial catalog=catalog_name
```

I get this exception:

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +78
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly() +32
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load() +25
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData) +160
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors) +166
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) +316
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection) +84
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly) +151
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetTypeUsage(Type entityCLRType) +35
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySetForNameAndType(String entitySetName, Type entityCLRType, String exceptionParameterName) +33
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet(String entitySetName) +66
   Projectname.DataAccess.EntitiesContainer.get_Users() in C:\Users\....\DataAccess\Model1.Context.cs:48
   Projectname.DataAccess.UserData.getTopRatedUsers(Int32 amount) in C:\Users\....\DataAccess\UserData.cs:220
```

Comment: different thing can cause this problem. Check this for more information :http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541962/unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-connected-with-entitydatasource . Does your problem happen only on Deployment? Or do you have the same on development environmet?

Comment: The problem occurred only during deployment. I have already checked the information of the site, but could not find any useful information. The deployment environment supports ASP.Net 4.0 and MS SQL 2008 R2 like my development environment. Ah and i don´t use an EntityDataSource in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting all my referenced assemblies to `copy local = true`.